# How to kill forever the Axialis IconWorkShop VS 2008 Plug-in

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins

I recently upgraded my IconWorkshop version to 6.5, and a VS 2008 plug-in was installed.
Now, I can't remove the toolbar create by the plug-in.

[alt text http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/3730/captureykp.png](http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/3730/captureykp.png)

I have tried:

- Hiding the toolbar
- Deleting the toolbar
- Disabling the plug-in

But when I restart VS this annowing window pop-ups, and the toolbar button is there again!
[alt text http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/695/capture2p.png](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/695/capture2p.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved the problem renaming these files:

```
IconWorkshopAddin.dll      -> IconWorkshopAddin.dll.old
IconWorkshopAddin2005.dll  -> IconWorkshopAddin2005.dll.old
```

in the program installed folder.

Comment: I also had to run VS as admin to end the infinite "Couldn't find plugin, do you want to remove?" dialog loop.